# Returning an inserted value into a variable with PostgreSQL RETURNING .. INTO clause

Tags: c++, oracle, postgresql

Following insert, the statement works fine with `Oracle`.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2) RETURNING col1 INTO :var ;
```

We can bind a variable to `:var` and execute the statement.

However, when the same query runs in a Postgres database it gives following error.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO".

What is the reason for this behavior?

I tried to run the query in a PL/pgSQL block and it works perfectly.

```
DO $$
DECLARE var integer;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "table_name "(
            "col1, "col2")
          VALUES (val1, val2)
          RETURNING "col1" INTO var;
END $$
```

But above query cannot use inside C++ code directly without PL/pgSQL block when we connect to a Postgres database. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.4. Since we support database agnostic software applications we need to clarify this behavior.

I expect both database support RETURNING .. INTO clause in the same way.

Answer (score 5):

In PostgreSQL, the SQL statement `INSERT ... RETURNING` doesn't support an `INTO` clause, same as `SELECT`.

Both statements support `INTO` only in PL/pgSQL.

You handle `INSERT ... RETURNING` just like `SELECT` in PostgresSQL — it returns a result set.

I don't know why Oracle treats `INSERT ... RETURNING` so complicated and different from `SELECT`; the design decision was probably made as an afterthought in the late Seventies.